# $\mathbb{P} (X) \rightarrow \{0,1\}^X $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For each non empty set $X$  the following function is bijective.
$\mathbb{P} (X) \rightarrow \{0,1\}^X $

[image]

you give $A \subset X$ and you should get?

I do not understand this symbol. what should you get.

Nor do I understand how can I prove this.

I do however see that my domain and codomain both have the cardinality $2^n$

However I do not see why it has to be bijective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $\chi_A$ is the map from $X$ into $\{0,1\}$ which maps all elements of $A$ into $1$ and all elements of $A^\complement$ into $0$. Sou your goal is to prove that the map $A\mapsto\chi_A$ is a bijection between $\mathcal P(A)$ and the set of all maps from $X$ into $\{0,1\}$. It's not hard. Its inverse is the map from $\{0,1\}^X$ into $\mathcal P(A)$ defined by $f\mapsto f^{-1}\bigl(\{1\}\bigr)$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, each subset $A$ of $X$ is mapped to the characteristic function $\chi_A:X\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ of $A$, namely
$$\chi_A(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & \mbox{if } x\in A\\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise.}
\end{array}
\right.$$
This gives a bijection as claimed.

Example: Let $X=\{a,b\}$.

1. $A=X$: $\chi_A(a)=\chi_A(b)=1$.
2. $A=\{a\}$: $\chi_A(a)=1, \chi_A(b)=0$.
3. $A=\{b\}$: $\chi_A(a)=0, \chi_A(b)=1$.
4. $A=\emptyset$: $\chi_A(a)=\chi_A(b)=0$.

Comment: See my example please.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

This may be one of those cases where trying to work out specific examples actually muddies the waters. Just follow the rules:

If $A\neq B$, prove that $\chi_A\neq \chi_B.$ (This is easy to prove.)

If $f:X\to \{0,1\}$ find a set $A\in \mathcal P(X)$ such that $\chi_A=f$. (Hint: consider $f^{-1}(1)$)

Comment: can you give me one example that applies just so i can imagine it correctly ?

Comment: $X=\mathbb R$ for example.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your amazing answers. I now understand the concept and have constructed my attempt to proof this assumption. Please review it and feel free to comment on suggestions or point out errors. I am thankful!

Claim:

If $X \ne \emptyset$ then follows $\mathcal P(X) \rightarrow \{0,1\}^X, A \rightarrow \chi_{(A)} $ is a bijective function.

Proof.

Let $\chi_A =\chi_B $.

Two functions are equal when their domain and codomain are equal. and $\forall k \in A,B : \chi_A (k) = \chi_B (k). \Rightarrow A=B $

Thus $\chi$ is injective.

Suppose $|X| = n $. Follows $\mathcal {|P(X)|}= 2^n = |\{0,1\}^X| $

Suppose $\exists h \in \{0,1\}^X : \nexists A \subset X : \chi_{(A)} =h $

$\Rightarrow \exists g \in \{0,1\}^X : \{\chi_{(g)}\}^{-1} > 1 $ due to cardinality.

$\unicode{x21af}$ to injectivity. $\Rightarrow \chi$ ist surjective.

$q.e.d$